# Codeigniter, limiting user to input reporting once a day

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter-3

I am just wondering is there a way to limit a user for reporting once a day on every project he has?
For instance, a user has 2 projects on progress and in one day, he must report the progress once per project a day

```
<div class="table-responsive">
   <table id="zero_config" class="table table-striped table-bordered display" style="width:100%">
     <thead>
       <tr>
         <th>No.</th>
         <th>Project</th>
         <th>Aksi</th>
       </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <?php 
      $i = 1;
      foreach($project as $row) { 
      ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $i++ ?>.</td>
        <td><?php echo $row->nama_project ?></td>
        <td><a href="<?php echo base_url('report/harian/'.$row->id_project) ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs btn-block"><i class="fa fa-file-code"></i> Report</a></td>
       </tr>
       <?php } ?>
     </tbody>
    </table>
   </div>
```

SQL

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('project');
$this->db->join('user', 'user.id_user = project.pic', 'right');
$this->db->join('pegawai', 'pegawai.id_pegawai = user.id_pegawai', 'right');
$this->db->where('project.pic', $id);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: can u post the code.

Comment: you can check as, when they report then store it with report id with current date, and check if same id with same data reported then do not allow to report.

Comment: Right, I'll give it a shot then

Comment: I'm sorry @DevsiOdedra but how do I put that condition, sorry